# Possible to flash factory ROMs on an encrypted phone using fastboot?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, 4.4-kitkat

I have the storage on my Nexus 4 encrypted using Android's built-in encryption feature. I'd like to update to 4.4 using one of the factory images provided by Google. If I follow the standard script included in the tarball (removing the option to wipe the phone), which uses fastboot, will fastboot do the right thing and prompt me for the encryption password? Or might it brick my phone by writing unencrypted data on top of an encrypted partition?

Comment: I believe fastboot will overwrite the *entire* partition, so it won't prompt you to decrypt the device because it's just going to blank out your data partition completely if you flash the userdata image. However, I also don't believe that you *need* to flash or wipe the data partition (if coming from a fully stock system), so if you flashed only the system and boot partitions it would be somewhat analogous to receiving a standard OTA update.

Comment: Yes, I'm coming from a fully stock system. The script that comes in Google's tarball does "fastboot -w update image-occam-krt16o.zip" - I was planning to remove the -w to avoid wiping the data partition. So, from your comment, @eldarerathis, I take it that the system partition is not covered by the encryption, so as long as that's the only partition I flash, I should be good?

Comment: Yes, encryption only covers your data partition. I've not used `fastboot update` before, but my understanding is that is somewhat akin to performing the OTA via the recovery system, which doesn't require you to decrypt your data (as far as I'm aware, anyway). Therefore, I would think that flashing without the `-w` flag would simply update your system/boot partitions and leave your data intact. Google's scripts always seem to wipe the data partition, but I think it's only because they expect people to use them more often to fully re-flash and wipe a device, and less for incremental updating.

Comment: Some of this is also a bit contingent on what exactly is in the .zip archive, though. It might be worth taking a quick look to see if there's anything for the data partition in the folder structure. Again, I've not used this method (I have generally flashed using their .img files instead), but putting modifications to `/data` in a ROM archive is fairly uncommon, in my experience. Also, since you have fastboot, any boot problems would at lest be recoverable (though you may end up losing your data or something if it got really wonky, I suppose).

Comment: It does include a "userdata.img" in the zip - I guess I'll just play it safe by only flashing boot.img and system.img .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record: this works fine, so long as you are careful not to flash the userdata partition. I was able to follow the instructions from [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/14/android-4-4-kitkat-factory-images-and-binaries-are-up-for-nexus-4-all-variants-of-nexus-7-2012-and-2013-and-nexus-10/) for flashing the factory image, including removing the "-w" option from the "fastboot update ..." command (this prevents the update from wiping the userdata partition).